# .htaccess pointing css, images and js to public folder bug

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently moved my custom build cms to another environment and now my rewrite doesn't work anymore and i can't figure it out. Can someone give me any hints? The things that have been changed is going from ubuntu to CentOs and from PHP 5.5 to php 5.3. My htacces looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#point css, images en js folders to Public folder
RewriteRule ^img/(.+)?$ Public/img/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)?$ Public/images/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^style/(.+)?$ Public/style/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.+)?$ Public/js/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.+)?$ Public/fonts/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.+)?$ Public/css/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

A friend of mine wrote this and is now on vacation. Thanks in advance

Update: mod rewrite seems to work, becouse it redirects me.

The problem seems to appear only on images, it works for my css and js, i don't think the problem is .htaccess related anymore

Answer (score 0):

Is mod_rewrite even active on your new system or does the error occur with this single .htaccess file only?

If you didn't set up the rewrite module you can follow this guide:

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/12/05/enable-mod_rewrite-in-a-ubuntu-server/

Comment: could be right. your mod_rewrite might not have been enabled.

Comment: It seems to work, i used this to try and redirect myself to yahoo and it worked:: Options +FollowSymLinks
Redirect /test.html http://www.yahoo.com

Comment: maybe the problem lies with the permissions of the images or the images folder. Can you access an image directly?